# Modeling a Physical Place inside iPhone Application

Tags: iphone, 3d, webview, webgl, modeling

I need to find a way to model a physical place inside an iPhone application. For example, I want to be able to take images for a restaurant and then use some tools or programming API to model this resturant as a 3d place and make the user able to navigate and explore the place and rooms.

I have thought about HTML 5 inside a web view but I don't think the WebGL is compatible with iPhone Web View (Safari Engine).

Can you please recommend a method, API, Commercial Library or anything to help me achieve this task?

Comment: This is far too broad of a question for us to answer. You're talking about taking still images, processing them to generate a 3-D model of an area, then representing that 3-D area on the device. Each one of those topics could fill chapters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to be able to display 3D models for IPhone. One of the most popular 3D engine is Unity3D:
http://unity3d.com/

It is extremely easy to start playing with Unity3D. You even have a free license with limited features:
http://unity3d.com/unity/licenses

Then, you now need to reconstruct a 3D model from pictures. This is not a trivial problem so it is better if you know some computer vision. You can try to play with OpenCV:
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Nuke from the Foundry has a decent start at the future of creating computer models from images. 
Basically it takes a high contrast point and tracks it through successive moments. Given hundreds and thousands of tracked points, the next step is to calculate the perspective change  between points.
Say two points are a known pixel distance apart at time zero and a certain time period later they are a different distance apart. This change in difference could be a bad tracking point. But assuming that the two points are perfectly tracking, then the distance change could be caused by a camera motion laterally or rotationally. And in real space a point further away from you will have a different perspective then a closer point . This perspective change is a mathematical certainty.

Initially the tracking is typically used to refilm a piece of film to stabilize it. But the process the software uses to analyze the film can be saved , it is often called a point cloud. connection of many close points that track very closely usually are because the points are parts of a surface, so a model can be built.

But my friend, we are barbarians to the speed and software that can do that perfectly yet. Or all the CG Artists out there would not have anything to model in Maya except fantasy monsters and space ships that don't exist yet....